# Some chars can't be printed in standard output

Tags: language-support, encoding, special-characters, system-language

I am using a server (by ssh) and as I am French I would like to be able to use characters such as "à", "ç" and "é". However they simply can't be printed in the standard output, whether when I press the corresponding key on my keyboard (it simply ignores the key), or when I run a script supposed to print them. For example a Python script will raise:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Following some advices I looked at the locale:

```
$ locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

So I opened the /etc/default/locale file, and changed it from:

```
LANG="C"
```

to

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

It still doesn't work, but a call to locale now tells me:

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Any ideas how I could fix this ?

Comment: hmm... strange that LANGUAGE is unset. Have you installed French? Try running `sudo update-locale LANGUAGE=fr_FR:fr`?

Comment: it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Actually it did, but only after I started a nex ssh session. Should I do that AND manually edit /usr/default/locale ? (presently I reverted this back to initial state)

Comment: no, `update-locale` updates `/etc/default/locale` for you (that's what it's supposed to do anyway. You can edit it yourself instead though.)

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by typing:  `LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF-8`, `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8` and the problem seems to be fixed. @FlorianDiesch: your link seems to be a similar problem but not exactly the same.

Comment: @AnneAunyme put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by the following commands:

```
sudo update-locale LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of those locale errors too by generating the fr_FR.UTF-8 locale:

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Comment: Actually I didn't seem to need that. What is it supposed to do? Modify /etc/default/locale ? Something else ?

Comment: @AnneAunyme: As I said, it generates the locale which you tells the system in `/etc/default/locale` to use. Setting `LANGUAGE` may be sufficient for certain aspects of GNU compatible programs, but you really should get rid of those error messages when running the `locale` command.

Comment: Those errors only occurred when I manually modified the file. For now (after reverting back to the initial file and applying my answer), everything seems to be fine.

Comment: @AnneAunyme: That sounds odd, but ok, in that case all is well. :)